# What are the scenarios if mining company around 4c decides to halt stock trading due to capital raising?

Tags: stocks, trading

Also have to say that before that trading halt announcement  the stock got +40% gain, anyway, does it usually mean that things are going forward and so the share price will climb higher or the price will decrease right after opening?

Comment: to the downvoter: I read this as asking for an explanation as to what an increase in capital will do for the price and value of a company and so answered in such a way as to make the question based on the non-opinion based question of how to work with increased capital and ROCE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the company in question is raising money to invest in expanding its operations (specifically lithium production but that is off topic for here). The stock price was rising on the back of (perceived) increases in demand for the company's products *but* in order to fulfil demand they need to either invest in higher production or increase prices. They chose to increase production by investing. To invest they needed to raise capital and so are going through the motions to do that.

The key question as to what will happen with their stock price after this is broken down into two parts: short term and long term:

In the short term the price is driven by the expectation of future profits (see below) *and* the behavioural expectations from an increase in interest in the stock caused by the fact that it is in the news. People who had never heard of the stock or thought of investing in the company have suddenly discovered it and been told that it is doing well and so "want a piece of it". This will exacerbate the effect of the news (broadly positive or negative) and will drive the price in the short run. The effect of extra leverage (assuming that they raise capital by writing bonds) also immediately increases the total value of the company so will increase the price somewhat.

The short term price changes usually pare back after a few months as the shine goes off and people take profits.

For investing in the long run you need to consider how the increase in capital will be used and how demand and supply will change. Since the company is using the money to invest in factors of production (i.e. making more product) it is the return on capital (or investment) employed (ROCE) that will inform the fundamentals underlying the stock price. The higher the ROCE, the more valuable the capital raised is in the future and the more profits and the company as a whole will grow. A questing to ask yourself is whether they can employ the extra capital at the same ROCE as they currently produce. It is possible that by investing in new, more productive equipment they can raise their ROCE but also possible that, because the lithium mines (or whatever) can only get so big and can only get so much access to the seams extra capital will not be as productive as existing capital so ROCE will fall for the new capital.